# Convergence of a double sum to an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are periodic continuous functions on $[0,1]$, what is the limit of following sum for $q\to \infty$ ?:

$$  \lim_{q \to \infty}\frac{1}{q^2}  \sum\limits_{k =0}^{q-1} \sum\limits_{a =0}^{q-1} f(\frac{k}{q}) g(\frac{k}{q}+\frac{a}{q}) $$

I guess it is $\int\limits_{0}^{1} \int\limits_{0}^{1} f(x) g(x+t) \; dt \; dx$, but it is not so obvious to prove it.

As the sums are linked I do not see how to come back to a classical Riemann sum converging to an integral.

Comment: How is it not a Riemann sum? Just that it is nested this time...

Comment: Once one notes that, by the periodicity of $g$, the double sum is also $$\frac{1}{q^2}  \sum\limits_{k =0}^{q-1} \sum\limits_{a =0}^{q-1} f(k/q) g(a/q),$$ the limit $$\int_0^1f(x)dx\cdot\int_0^1g(x)dx$$ becomes pretty clear.